# How to Prevent Image Lightbox from Opening on Mobile Screens?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

In my website's image gallery section, I have an image lightbox set to open when an image is clicked on.

My question is how would I prevent the lightbox from opening ONLY on mobile screens?

I have never altered javascript for different screen sizes nor have I ever used javascript within a media query so this is new to me...

```
<script>





// Open the Modal
function openModal() {
  document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("navclose").style.display = "none";

}



// Close the Modal
function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("navclose").style.display = "";
}

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";

}
</script>
```

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <span class="close cursor"  onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
         <div class="modal-content">

                <div class="mySlides">
                  <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
                  <img class="grid-image" src="images/grid.jpg" style="width:100%"> <h5 id="imagecaption">Pfieffer Beach Restoration </h5>
                </div>

                <div class="mySlides">
                  <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
                  <img class="grid-image" src="images/gridgallery2.jpeg" style="width:100%"> <h5 id="imagecaption">Birchwood Condo Gardens</h5>
                </div>

                <div class="mySlides">
                  <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
                  <img class="grid-image"  src="images/gridgallery3.jpg" style="width:100%"> <h5 id="imagecaption"> Pershing Square Master Plan </h5>
                </div>

                <div class="mySlides">
                  <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
                  <img class="grid-image" src="images/gridgallery1.jpg" style="width:100%"> <h5 id="imagecaption"> UCLA Quad Redesign</h5>
                </div>



              <!-- Next/previous controls -->
                <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
                <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>


             

               
        </div>
    </div>


</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's test if `pointer-events: none` is stronger than event listeners.

```js
function lightBox() {
  alert("yay you are not on mobile")

}
```

```css
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  button {
    pointer-events: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="lightBox()">Click for lightbox</button>
(try it on mobile size snippet vs full page)
```

Yes! so there you have it.

```css
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .mySlides {
    pointer-events: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But how would I apply the code to my specific lightbox?

Comment: the idea is to apply that to a container of each image in order to prevent pointer events on it. answer edited

Comment: Apply what exactly to each image?

Comment: just add the css above